EC2 instance is not accessible by domain name
Getting error site not reached when I access EC2 instance by domain name.
When I do ping www.domain.com it works.
When I do access my ec2 instance with public IP address it also works
DNS is also propagated!!!
I have created 2 record

Name: Leave blannk
Value: Public IP address of your EC2 instance.

Create another record set with the following details:

Type: Alias.
Name: www (for the subdomain).
Alias Target: Select the root domain.

It would be really great if you could help me.

How are you attempting to 'access' the EC2 instance? Are you pointing your web browser to the domain name? Have you installed a web server on the instance? What happens if you just put the IP address in your browser (eg http://1.2.3.4)?

To associate a domain name with an EC2 instance, you should:

Create an Elastic IP address, which is a static IP address
Associated the Elastic IP address with the EC2 instance
Create an A-Record in your DNS system that points to the Elastic IP address (eg 1.2.3.4)

